# favicon is showing when I run locally but not showing on Heroku app

Tags: heroku

I checked that https://myapp.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico is OK, and favicon is sit under public folder, how to fix it? thanks.

Comment: This problem is not related to `autodesk-forge` or `autodesk-bim360`. You should remove this tags and add some code to help understanding how you code your website. This way we will get more informations to help you solving this problem.

Comment: thanks AlexAR, I replaced w/ Heroku so it makes more sense

Comment: Please read [ask]. We're going to need a lot more information than this. Are you seeing 500 messages for `/favicon.ico` in your server logs? Are you seeing the same in your browser's devtools? Is this actually working, but whatever browser you're using just isn't displaying it properly?

Comment: thanks Chris, turned out clearing cache is actually working, only in next day, perhaps because my habit of restarting computer every day.